# nouislider with angular2 - set is not a function

Tags: angular, nouislider

I am using a 2-handle `nouislider`. It works great but when I try to update the handle positions from the code, I keep getting the error: *set is not a function*. What am I missing?

```
//HTML

<nouislider #mrangeslider [connect]="true" [step]=".05"
          [(ngModel)]="sliderMRangeSel" (change)="updateSliderM($event)"
          [min]="sliderMBounds[0]"
          [max]="sliderMBounds[1]">
</nouislider>

//in main module

import { NouisliderModule } from 'ng2-nouislider';

// in component

@ViewChild("mrangeslider") mSliderEl : ElementRef;
sliderMBounds = [1,2];
sliderMRangeSel = [1.25,1.75];
...
this.sliderMRangeSel = [1.25,1.75];
this.mSliderEl.set(this.sliderMRangeSel); // trying to update the handles
```

In browser too I get the same:

```
> this.mSliderEl.set([1.25,1.75])
  VM492:1 Uncaught TypeError: this.mSliderEl.set is not a function
// but there is a `set` property defined, no observers
> this.mSliderEl.set
  EventEmitter {_isScalar: false, observers: Array(0), closed: false,
                   isStopped: false, hasError: false, …}
```

Obviously I have missed some step. I am using `nouislider` v13.1.0 with `angular` v7.1.0 running on chrome browser Windows 10.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the template reference variable `#mrangeslider` is set on the slider component, the default value given by `@ViewChild()` is the `NouisliderComponent` class instance. I assume that this is what you want. With it, you can access the slider properties and methods. If needed, you could get a reference to the component HTML host element by setting the `read` property to `ElementRef`:

```
@ViewChild("mrangeslider") mSliderComp: NouisliderComponent;
@ViewChild("mrangeslider", { read: ElementRef }) mSliderEl: ElementRef;
```

That being said, since `sliderMRangeSel` is bound with `[(ngModel)]`, the component should adjust automatically when changing the range values, without having to call a method of the component.

```
setSliderRange() {
  // The slider will adjust after selecting the range
  this.sliderMRangeSel = [1.15, 1.9];
}
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-o3rm2x?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) for a demo.

Comment: Thanks!! It turned out I was only updating one element of the model array. So I changed my code to make a temp copy, update the element and then replace the model array, then update model => handle position update. I wonder what's the root cause. No need to get the reference and call set().

Comment: It is because Angular detects if the value bound to `ngModel` has changed. Here the bound value is the array `sliderMRangeSel`. If you only change an item of the array, no change is detected by Angular because the array reference has not changed. In that case, the view is not updated.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. IIRC this is a 180 from angularJS where if the reference was changed then it lost tracking. Now it's only tracking the reference. I wish the docs were clearer

Answer (score 0):

`ElementRef` only contains 1 property -- `nativeElement`.

https://angular.io/api/core/ElementRef#properties